# Unwrapping Trees

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I am struggling with UV Unwrapping my trees in blender cycles. I am trying to find out the best and the shortest way of doing this stuff. I have already tried to create a Smart UV Project: [image: SmartUV]
As I have predicted, it could not be a good solution because of the strange directions of textures and easily noticeable seams. Then I tried to do the Cube Projection: [image: Cube Projection]
In this case the direction of the texture was right, but unfortunately seams were even more obvious. I have tested this method also on a more low poly mesh. In this case seams were not as easy to notice as they were in the high poly mesh - acceptable result, but I do need more triangles (20k vs 100k). At last I tried to mark the seams and then unwrap the mesh- good result, but it took so long in comparison to the other methods. Is there any other method? Maybe there's a way to shorten the process of marking seams?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79338/29586

Comment: Yep, that's such a good method. Even without testing it, I know that it would work perfectly, but it might be a bit laborious. Will give it a shot as this is going to be really accurate. Thanks